# Is there a way to change the color of the navigation bar? Or to make it transparent

Tags: navigation

Some apps change the color of the navigation bar color to their color scheme (or even make it transparent). But most of the time it remains black. Is there a way to change its color for all screens or to make transparent?

It's okay if rooting or custom ROM is needed for this.

Comment: Navbar Apps by Damian Piwowarski from play store is capable of changing navigation bar color equivalent to that of opened app color also with more customization.

Comment: @RahulGopi Good thing! But it seems to have some compatibility problems with Nova Launcher. I'll take a deeper look into the setting later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install GravityBox compatible with your Android version. It requires a rooted device with a compatible Xposed Framework installed. Once you install it, enable its module in Xposed Installer app, launch it, go to Navigation tweaks, and make changes which you are looking for. Master toggle listed there requires a reboot for changes to take effect.

Comment: I'll take a look.

Comment: BTW I couldn't try your proposal because that phone has some other issues incompatible with my understanding of using a smartphone, so it's going to be sold :)